# Opening an application (Chromium) highlights the bad shortcut indock

Tags: launcher, icons

When I launch (by clicking on the icon) Chromium, the red point is instead placed under the icon of slack.

[image: extract of my dock, after I launched chromium]

I tried the following :

- changed the StartupWMClass value in slack_slack.desktop¹
- close slack
- remove slack from the dock
- changed the Exec line, replacing slack by slack_nonexistent
  I got each tiome the same behaviour : clicking on the Chromium icon opes a new window, but the new dot is placed under the slack icon.

¹ There are many slack.desktop files, but changing this one make the icon blink (and it doesn't work anymore if I change the Exec line - so I guess this is the good file)

Why on earth would Ubuntu be confused ? Any idea, any test is welcome.

I made my question generic because I don't know what it is related to.

```
$ cat /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/slack_slack.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
X-SnapInstanceName=slack
Name=Slack
StartupWMClass=ISaidSlack
Comment=Slack Desktop
GenericName=Slack Client for Linux
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/slack_slack.desktop /snap/bin/slack_x %U
Icon=/snap/slack/15/usr/share/pixmaps/slack.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;InstantMessaging;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/slack;


$ cat /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Chromium Web Browser
Name[fr]=Navigateur Web Chromium
# (other i18n strings)
GenericName=Web Browser
GenericName[fr]=Navigateur Web
# (other i18n strings)
Comment=Access the Internet
Comment[fr]=Accéder à Internet
# (other i18n strings)
Exec=chromium-browser %U
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=chromium-browser
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=NewWindow;Incognito;TempProfile;
X-AppInstall-Package=chromium-browser

[Desktop Action NewWindow]
Name=Open a New Window
Name[fr]=Ouvrir une nouvelle fenêtre
# (other i18n strings)
Exec=chromium-browser

[Desktop Action Incognito]
Name=Open a New Window in incognito mode
Name[fr]=Ouvrir une nouvelle fenêtre en mode navigation privée
# (other i18n strings)
Exec=chromium-browser --incognito

[Desktop Action TempProfile]
Name=Open a New Window with a temporary profile
Name[fr]=Ouvrir une nouvelle fenêtre avec un profil temporaire
# (other i18n strings)
Exec=chromium-browser --temp-profile
```